# Why can you use a previously undeclared name in a match?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I'm experiencing a problem understanding this code from the second chapter of the book:

```
let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
    Ok(num) => num,
    Err(_) => continue,
};
```

My problem is with `Ok(num) => num`: `parse()` returns a value (either `Ok` or `Err`), `match` compares that returned value to the first arm. If those match, the expression will execute the statement beside the first arm, right?

In `Ok(num)`, `num` seems to have popped up abruptly, since there was no declaration of `num` in previous code. Same with the statement, `=> num`: `num` was suddenly in scope. So

1. If I'm guessing it right, `match` matches the returned value with `Ok()`, then assigns whatever number that is (inside `Ok`) to `num`. But why is `num` at the right suddenly usable?
2. If I guessed right, what's the difference of `Ok(num)` and `Ok(_)`?

Comment: For the best understanding you should read the book further, namely [chapter 6](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-00-enums.html) where enums and pattern matching will be explained.

Comment: The `num` in the pattern is the declaration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we start with where `Ok` and `Err` come from, we might get a better idea. They are a part of the [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/) enum defined like:

```
enum Result<T, E> {
   Ok(T),
   Err(E),
}
```

`T` and `E` are generic types. `match` itself is like C's `switch` statement but more flexible.

The general form of `match` itself is:

```
match value {
    pattern => expr,
    ...
}
```

> If those match, the expression will execute the statement beside the first arm, right?

Yes

> But why is `num` at the right suddenly usable?

Because `match` matches *patterns* to the left of the `=>` in each arm. It can unpack tuples, match struct fields, borrow parts of a value, etc.

> If I guessed right, what's the difference of `Ok(num)` and `Ok(_)`?

`_` is a wildcard pattern and matches everything.

The difference between `Ok(num)` and `Ok(_)` is that in first case you are asking that if the `Result` is the `Ok` variant then store its value of type `T` in `num`. In the second case, you are saying that you do not care what value `Ok` holds — as long as the `Result` is the `Ok` variant you want to execute something.

Remember that when you use `_` in a pattern, you cannot use `_` inside the code i.e. this will not work because `_` is not an identifier:

```
let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
    Ok(_) => _,
    Err(_) => continue,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

short answer. `patterns match` can destruct structs, enums... [see here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#destructuring-to-break-apart-values)

signature of `parse` is `pub fn parse<F>(&self) -> Result<F, <F as FromStr>::Err>`. There is a generic type `F` in it.

The compiler finds `let guess: u32 =`, and it infers that what you need is `u32`. So the `F` is `u32` here.

Then the patterns match destructing extracts `num` from `Ok<u32>`

Comment: If you answer a question, please try to answer all of them (although it should only be one question at a time, but it's not the case this time).